# Import database schema in MongoDB

Tags: json, database, mongodb, schema, mongodb-compass

I created json schema for MongoDB. It's look like:

```
{
      "schemaType": "Collection",
      "name": "Manufacturier",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "description": "...",
      "fields": [
        {
          "schemaType": "Field",
          "name": "_id",
          "type": "ObjectId",
          "required": true,
          "unique": true,
          "defaultValue": "",
          "description": "...",
          "index": 0,
          "customProps": []
        }
      ]
    }
...
```

Can I import this schema into mongodb? And how (if it's possible)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, can iimport this schema into mongo, to mongo can validate input documents

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/schema-validation/ ne?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the biggest advantage of mongoDB that you can insert documents without the need to define the schema in advance , afcourse there is option to add schema validation rules as commented by [@Alex Blex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/schema-validation/) , but this is limiting the main reason you would like to use noSQL mongoDB database instead of other possible data storage system ...